# Having trouble dealing with Moment JS (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I am having trouble with Moment JS.  Basically, I have some metadata for a radio station, and in my php call, I get in return the 'duration' of the song, the 'timestamp' when the song started.

I did some calculation with Moment JS to get the time when the song will be finished, and then I find the difference. However, the difference is returning a negative number, which then breaks the app.

If someone can help me that would be great.

This is my plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/joVLYdTKY5dZBOTNfTOI

Services

```
angular.module('starter', [])

.run(function(CurrentTrack){
   CurrentTrack.refreshTrackData();
})

.controller('radioCtrl', function($scope,CurrentTrack) {  
   console.log(CurrentTrack);
   $scope.CurrentTrack = CurrentTrack;  
})

.service('CurrentTrack',function(radioData,$timeout){

   var currentTrack = this;

   this.setTrackData = function(trackData){

      currentTrack.coverUrl = trackData.cover_url;
      currentTrack.title = trackData.title;
      currentTrack.artist = trackData.artist;
      currentTrack.duration = moment.duration(parseInt(trackData.duration));
      currentTrack.startedAt = moment.unix(trackData.timestamp);
      currentTrack.finishesAt = moment(this.startedAt.add(this.duration));
      currentTrack.updateIn = this.finishesAt.diff(moment());

      currentTrack.refreshing = false;
      return currentTrack.updateIn;
   }

   this.refreshTrackData = function(){
      currentTrack.refreshing = true;
      return radioData.refresh()
         .then(currentTrack.setTrackData.bind(currentTrack))
         .then(currentTrack.scheduleUpdate);
   }

   this.scheduleUpdate = function(ms){
      console.log(ms)
      $timeout(function(){
         currentTrack.refreshTrackData()
      },ms);
      return;
   }  
})
```

Factory

```
.factory('radioData', function($http,$timeout) {
   var retries = 0;

   function parseResponse(response){
      retries = 0;
      if(!response.data.results){
         console.log('no results')
         return false;
      }
      console.log('refreshed...')
      return response.data.results[0];
   }

   function makeRequest(){
      console.log('refreshing...')
      return $http.get('http://radio-sante-animale.fr/blah11.php?  callback=jsonpCallback')
   }

   function retry(errResponse){
      console.error('timed out');
      //wait for a sec
      retries++;
      if(retries > 5){
         throw new Error('timed out after 5 attempts!');
      }
      //oops
      return $timeout(makeRequest,1000).then(null,retry);
   }

   var radioData = {
      refresh: function() {
         return makeRequest()
           .then(null,retry)
           .then(parseResponse)
           .catch(function(err){
               console.log(err);
           });
      }
   };
   return radioData;
});
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Basically, the app goes crazy and breaks because some reason 'currentTrack.updateIn' returns a negative number, I cannot understand why.

Comment: Your plunker seems to work correctly. Is this problem consistently there or does it just fail occasionally?

Comment: @DTing It fails a lot actually - I am wondering if it has to do with the API I am using, there are many timeouts with this API.

However, when I console log the this.startedAt & this.finishedAt, it seems to be the same, so I am wondering if this is 'causing some sort of problem.

Comment: I feel there is some aysynchornous problem going on, I think the 'this.finishedAt' does not get the data in time for 'updateIn' to work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my side, it worked by adding ***Math.abs*** in your $timeout method

```
this.scheduleUpdate = function(ms) {
    console.log( 'update in :' + ms)
    $timeout(function() {
        currentTrack.refreshTrackData()
    }, Math.abs(ms));
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I changed:

```
currentTrack.finishesAt = moment(this.startedAt.add(this.duration));
```

to:

```
currentTrack.finishesAt = moment(currentTrack.startedAt).add(currentTrack.duration);
```

In the original code you are mutating the `startedAt` time then cloning. I also changed all the `this` to `currentTrack` to make it more consistent.

**The problem**

The bug manifests when there is a difference in the time the server is keeping and the time that the client is keeping, (not because you have anything reversed).

Basically the server sends you `trackData.timestamp` which you parse and convert into a moment to use as your `startedAt` time. Then you change the `trackData.duration` into a `moment.duration` and add it to the `startedAt` time to get your `finishesAt` time.

If the time that the client is keeping is running ahead the server's time, the calculated `finishesAt` time will be earlier than when the actual song ends. An exaggerated example makes this more clear.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout, $interval, Server) {
  function updateTime() {
    $scope.serverTime = moment().subtract(1,'s');
    $scope.clientTime = moment();  
  }
  
  function refreshInfo() {
    Server.getSongInfo().then(parseInfo).then(scheduleRefresh);
  };
  
  function parseInfo(trackData) {
    $scope.songInfo = trackData;
    var startedAt = trackData.timestamp;
    $scope.finishesAt = moment(startedAt).add(trackData.duration, 'ms');
    $scope.updateIn = $scope.finishesAt.diff(moment());
    return $scope.updateIn;
  }
  
  function scheduleRefresh(updateIn) {
    if (updateIn < 0) {
      $scope.bugged = true;
    } else {
      $scope.bugged = false;
    }
    $timeout(refreshInfo, updateIn);
  }
  
  $scope.songInfo = "loading";
  updateTime();
  refreshInfo();
  
  $interval(updateTime, 1000);
});

app.service('Server', function($timeout, $interval) {
  var song = {
    duration: 5000
  };
  
  this.getSongInfo = function() {
    return $timeout(function() { return this.trackData });
  };
  
  function nextSong() {  
    this.trackData = {
      duration: song.duration,
      timestamp: moment().subtract(1,'s')
    };
  }
  
  nextSong();
  
  $interval(nextSong, song.duration);
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.row {  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}
.col {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.3" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="moment.js@2.8.3" data-semver="2.8.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col' ng-class='{red:bugged}'>
        <h3>Song Info</h3>
        <div>{{ songInfo }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col'>
        <h3>Server</h3>
        <div>{{ serverTime.format("hh:mm:ss") }}</div>
      </div>
      <div class='col'>
        <h3>Finishes At</h3>
        <div>{{ finishesAt.format("hh:mm:ss") }}</div>
      </div>   
      <div class='col'>
        <h3>Update In</h3>
        <div>{{ updateIn }}</div>
      </div>  
      <div class='col'>
        <h3>Client</h3>
        <div>{{ clientTime.format("hh:mm:ss") }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Whenever the song info div is red, the client is in the loop where it is requesting new track info and parsing out a finish time that is earlier than the current moment, which immediately makes it request new track info.

```js
angular.module('starter', [])

.run(function(CurrentTrack) {
  CurrentTrack.refreshTrackData();
})

.controller('radioCtrl', function($scope, CurrentTrack) {
  $scope.CurrentTrack = CurrentTrack;

})

.service('CurrentTrack', function(radioData, $timeout) {

  var currentTrack = this;

  this.setTrackData = function(trackData) {
    currentTrack.coverUrl = trackData.cover_url;
    currentTrack.title = trackData.title;
    currentTrack.artist = trackData.artist;
    currentTrack.duration = moment.duration(parseInt(trackData.duration));
    currentTrack.startedAt = moment.unix(trackData.timestamp);
    currentTrack.finishesAt = moment(currentTrack.startedAt).add(currentTrack.duration);
    currentTrack.updateIn = currentTrack.finishesAt.diff(moment())
    
    console.log(currentTrack, trackData);
    currentTrack.refreshing = false;
    return currentTrack.updateIn;
  }

  this.refreshTrackData = function() {
    currentTrack.refreshing = true;
    return radioData.refresh()
      .then(currentTrack.setTrackData)
      .then(currentTrack.scheduleUpdate);
  }

  this.scheduleUpdate = function(ms) {
    console.log("update in " + ms)
    $timeout(function() {
      currentTrack.refreshTrackData()
    }, ms);
    return;
  }
})


.factory('radioData', function($http, $timeout) {

  var retries = 0;

  function parseResponse(response) {
    retries = 0;
    if (!response.data.results) {
      console.log('no results')
      return false;
    }
    console.log('response parsed.')
    return response.data.results[0];
  }

  function makeRequest() {
    console.log('making request.')
    return $http.get('http://radio-sante-animale.fr/blah11.php?callback=jsonpCallback')
  }

  function retry(errResponse) {
    console.error('timed out');
    //wait for a sec
    retries++;
    if (retries > 5) {
      throw new Error('timed out after 5 attempts!');
    }
    //oops
    return $timeout(makeRequest, 1000).then(parseResponse, retry);
  }

  var radioData = {
    refresh: function() {
      return makeRequest()
        .then(parseResponse, retry)
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  };
  return radioData;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="starter">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.3" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="moment.js@2.8.3" data-semver="2.8.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="radioCtrl">
  <h3>Current Music Information</h3>
  <p ng-show="CurrentTrack.refreshing">refreshing...</p>

  <img style="width:300px;height:300px;" src="{{CurrentTrack.coverUrl}}" alt="">
  <p>
    Title : {{ CurrentTrack.title }}
    <br />Artist : {{ CurrentTrack.artist }}
    <br />The song started at {{ CurrentTrack.startedAt }}
    <br />Duration of the song {{ CurrentTrack.duration.asSeconds() }} seconds
    <br />Finishes At {{ CurrentTrack.finishesAt }}
    <br />Update In {{ CurrentTrack.updateIn }}
    <br />
</body>

</html>
```

I'm actually not sure the best approach to fixing this problem but hopefully some one has a better answer.

A hack solution is to add more time (some acceptable amount of error) to the `finishesAt` to give a little leeway.

```
currentTrack.finishesAt = moment(currentTrack.startedAt).add(currentTrack.duration).add(1, 's');
```

Comment: thank you so much for spending some time helping me out on this algorithm. It is very clear what are you trying to do, and it helps me out a lot. I will study what you programmed and continue to make sure this thing works correctly.

Answer (score -1):

From http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

> If the moment is earlier than the moment you are passing to
>   moment.fn.diff, the return value will be negative.

You need to reverse the dates in your diff.

EDIT: Like this -

```
currentTrack.updateIn = moment().diff(this.finishesAt);
```

Comment: This is not correct. `this.finishesAt` is almost certainly later than `moment()` unless there is a problem with `currentTrack.startedAt = moment.unix(trackData.timestamp);`

Comment: Reread that statement once more and understand it. If the moment (current date time) is earlier than the moment you are passing in to the diff function (this.finishesAt), the return value will be negative. So yes, this is correct. I even tested it in your plnkr.

Comment: Look at the first example. `var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b) // 86400000` `a` is later than `b` `a.diff(b)` is positive, `this.finishesAt` is later than `moment()`. `this.finishesAt.diff(moment())` should be positive. `moment().diff(this.finishesAt)` should be negative.